# Offset Argument in Statsmodels.api GLM

Tags: python, statsmodels

In R when modeling poisson survival, I could simply wrap the exposure predictor with the offset keyword like this:

```
glm(deaths ~ offset(exposure), family=poisson, data=data)
```

The summary would produce only the estimation of the intercept.

In, Statsmodels.api, what would be the equivalent code to apply offset on exposure predictor?
I've tried the following:

```
smf.glm('dead~exposure',\
         data=datgrp,\
         offset=np.log(datgrp['exposure']), \     
         family=sm.families.Poisson(\
         link=sm.families.links.log)).fit().summary()
```

But, the returning code produces coefficient measures for intercept and exposure, which is inaccurate to the example problem I'm resolving.

Comment: try `smf.glm('dead~1', ...)`  offset or exposure should not be included in the explanatory variables. It will be added automatically with a coefficient fixed at 1.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you very much!